# PHP URLDecode / UTF8_Encode Character Set Issues with special characters

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding, urlencode

I'm passing a pound symbol `£` to a PHP page which has been URLEncoded by ASP as `%C2%A3`.

The problem:

```
urldecode("%C2%A3") // £
ord(urldecode("%C2%A3")) // get the character number - 194
ord("£") // 163  - somethings gone wrong, they should match
```

This means when I do `utf8_encode(urldecode("%C2%A3"))` I get `Â£`

However doing `utf8_encode("£")` I get `£` as expected

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think `ord()` is multibyte compatible. It's probably returning only the code for the first character in the string, which is Â. Try to `utf8_decode()` the string before calling `ord()` on it and see if that helps.

```
ord(utf8_decode(urldecode("%C2%A3"))); // This returns 163
```

Comment: Thanks, this sorted my issue, wrapped utf8_decode() around the $_POST["myvar"] and its all working as expected

Answer (score 3):

if you try

```
var_dump(urldecode("%C2%A3"));
```

you'll see

```
string(2) "£"
```

because this is 2-byte character and ord() returns value of first one (194 = Â)

Comment: Why does ord("£") return 163? The rest of my code works fine if I hard code in "£" so I'm looking for PHP to recognize this as char 163

Comment: Because you typed it yourself.

Comment: @Arkh thats not that helpful as I was trying to get PHP to recognize a POSTED variable of "£" as char 163.

Comment: @Igor K - php recognizes `£` as 163 (hex: A3), that's correct, but you've got 194 because before **A3** stands **C2** and `194=C2`... Look above `String(2)` but you see just `"£"`, first character is not visible but still exists. in ut8 you'll see `Â£` instead of `£` that's difference.

Answer (score 2):

Some infos about urldecode and UTF-8 can be found in [the first comment of the urldecode documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php#101401). It seems to be a known problem.

Comment: Great catch! That seems to describe the problem.

Comment: This is not a problem nor a bug in php.  The comment refers to a bad client encoding which is probably happening because of a missing UTF8 meta tag/header.  You will get unexpected results if you try to fix a bad request like that.

Answer (score -1):

The [first comment](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.urldecode.php#101401) on php.net for urlencode() [explains](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-forms-utf-8.en.php) why this is and suggests this code for correcting it:

```
<?php
function to_utf8( $string ) {
// From http://w3.org/International/questions/qa-forms-utf-8.html
    if ( preg_match('%^(?:
      [\x09\x0A\x0D\x20-\x7E]            # ASCII
    | [\xC2-\xDF][\x80-\xBF]             # non-overlong 2-byte
    | \xE0[\xA0-\xBF][\x80-\xBF]         # excluding overlongs
    | [\xE1-\xEC\xEE\xEF][\x80-\xBF]{2}  # straight 3-byte
    | \xED[\x80-\x9F][\x80-\xBF]         # excluding surrogates
    | \xF0[\x90-\xBF][\x80-\xBF]{2}      # planes 1-3
    | [\xF1-\xF3][\x80-\xBF]{3}          # planes 4-15
    | \xF4[\x80-\x8F][\x80-\xBF]{2}      # plane 16
)*$%xs', $string) ) {
        return $string;
    } else {
        return iconv( 'CP1252', 'UTF-8', $string);
    }
}
?>
```

Also you should decide wether you want your final html you send to the browser to be in utf-8 or some other encoding, otherwise you will continue having Â£ characters in your code.

Comment: Data is being passed to a PHP built in class that expects UTF-8 encoding. Do you see any reason to use that function instead of utf8_decode()?

Comment: Because %C2%A3 is not utf-8 - utf-8-pund would be %20%A4. What you are getting from your ASP-Code is iso-8859-1 characters.
This function checks wether a string is valid utf-8 and if not it converts it to utf8. Also using utf8_decode() gives you iso-8859-1 characters not utf-8 ones.

Comment: This function just makes a guess at the encoding and does a utf8_encode if it doesn't find any utf8 characters.  You should never need anything like this if you fix the issue at the source.